# In AWS IAM, What is the Purpose/Use of the "Path" Variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In IAM, what is the purpose/use of the "Path" variable when creating an IAM User via the CLI or API?

Answer (score 47):

The path variable in IAM is used for grouping related users and groups in a unique namespace, usually for organizational purposes.

From [Friendly Names and Paths](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-friendly-names):

> If you are using the IAM API or AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) to create IAM entities, you can also give the entity an optional path. You can use a single path, or nest multiple paths as if they were a folder structure. For example, you could use the nested path /division_abc/subdivision_xyz/product_1234/engineering/ to match your company's organizational structure. You could then create a policy to allow all users in that path to access the policy simulator API. To view this policy, see IAM: Access the Policy Simulator API Based on User Path. For additional examples of how you might use paths, see IAM ARNs.

For example, a large organization may have users in paths /WestRegion/AZ and /EastRegion/NY.  This would correspond to internal divisions of the organization.

Here are some examples from the above document:

An IAM user called Bob in a given account:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob
```

Another different user Bob with a path reflecting an organization chart:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/Bob
```

An IAM group:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/Developers
```

An IAM group with a path:

`arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/product_A/Developer`

Note that this metadata is not exposed in the Console. My guess is that usage of a user `path` is more suited for large organizations, or advanced users, that would normally rely on CloudFormation and/or the AWS CLI for managing their AWS resources.  For example, the `--path-prefix` is a parameter to `aws iam list-users`.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-users.html

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for the note (and, please be assured, I was familiar with the part of the IAM Manual you cited). Given the way you describe IAM paths, they are similar to "tags" used elsewhere in AWS--with the potential for [optional] addition of a hierarchy (e.g., organization)...is this your interpretation. Any idea(s) as to why Paths cannot be provisioned/manipulated via the Console?

Comment: Yes they somewhat like tags, but really are more like paths/folders.  As to why they they are not exposed in the Console, my only guess is they are suited more for large organizations that would normally rely on CloudFormation and the CLI - they are used in both.  The `--path-prefix` is a parameter to `aws iam list-users`. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-users.html

Comment: So it has it's logical organization benefit, but the real benefit is limiting and delegating access to IAM actions.  You can make IAM policies that say "let users assign themselves groups `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/* `.  Or you can protect certain roles/users by placing them in an `/admin/` path.  Then, put a Deny rule on everyone not on the path so they cannot delete a user or mess with a policy on that /admin/ prefix.

Comment: You can't have a user named `Bob` on 2 different paths. When you try to create a second user you will get `An error occurred (EntityAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateUser operation: User with name Bob already exists.`.  Same is true for other IAM resources that have a path.

Comment: As of Oct, 2023, IAM path is exposed in the console. Click on the `Cog Button` in the top right corner and configure `Preferences` where you could select visible columns - Path.